# get array of sentences

Tags: javascript

I've got a textarea with several senteces.(. is a divider). How to get array of sentences?
I mean for example. `hello world. it's hello world.hello.` and the result array is - `[hello world], [it's hello world], [hello]`

Comment: [`What have you tried?`](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Nothing. I don't know methods like `split`(C#) in javascript because it's my second day learning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `split` method.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

var sentenceArray = str.split("\. |\.")

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split()` to split the string into an array:

```
> "hello world. it's hello world.hello.".split('.')
["hello world", " it's hello world", "hello", ""]
```